# Having issues adding textures to my model, directx11

Tags: c++, directx-11

Okay so loading in a model works fine but when I try to add a texture or lighting they become stretched, I think it is having problems sharing vertices. I have tried changing the sampler_desc address as well as messing around with the input layout but no luck. [The results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXqc7.jpg)

```
 HRESULT Model::CreateTextureSampler(char* filename) {

    hr = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, filename,
        NULL, NULL,
        &m_pTexture0, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) // Dont fail if error is just a warning 
        return hr;

    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC sampler_desc;
    ZeroMemory(&sampler_desc, sizeof(sampler_desc));
    sampler_desc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    sampler_desc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sampler_desc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sampler_desc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sampler_desc.MinLOD = 0;
    sampler_desc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
    hr = m_pD3DDevice->CreateSamplerState(&sampler_desc, &m_pSampler0);
    if (FAILED(hr)) // Dont fail if error is just a warning 
        return hr;
}

HRESULT Model::CreateInputLayout()
{
    // Create and set the input layout object 
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC m_iedesc[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0,0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "NORMAL", 0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
    };

    hr = m_pD3DDevice->CreateInputLayout(m_iedesc, 4, M_VS->GetBufferPointer(),
        M_VS->GetBufferSize(), &m_pInputLayout);
    if (FAILED(hr)) // Dont fail if error is just a warning 
        return hr;

    m_pImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(m_pInputLayout);

    m_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the changes, I'm new, didn't know how to format things

Comment: You are welcome for the format fix. For code indentation tabs use `ctrl+k`

Answer (score 0):

When I'm looking at your line of code and I see this line here:

> ```
> "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
> ```

You are passing to the input element descriptor for the tex coord with a third parameter of `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT`. You might want to check this flag to see if this is causing your problem.

Normally texture coords are a vec2 object when using simple textures, unless if you are using a 3D Texture.

You might want to change this to `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT`, and give the appropriate [S,T] or [P,Q] vertices for the texture file. Textures are normally images stored in memory linearly but are representing a MxN structure.

Comment: Thank you, however, I have changed this after I posted this haha. The same issue occurs.